# How use c# to convert mongodb BsonDateTime (UTC) to local time

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime

In my C# console application project I'm using MongoDB.Driver.2.4.3 with connection to MongoDB 3.2.10.

How would I convert "playerInBrazil.birthdate" in my code which is defined as BsonDateTime (I believe this is in UTC) to my local datetime value (Eastern Standard Time)?

I was trying to do subtract operation(not allowed) and DateTime.ToLocalTime Method () but couldn't make it work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime myTimeConvert = DateTime.Now;
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var DB = client.GetDatabase("football");

        var players = DB.GetCollection<Player>("players");

        var playersInBrazil = players.AsQueryable()
                         .Where(p => p.country == "Brazil");
        foreach (var playerInBrazil in playersInBrazil)
        {
            Console.Write(playerInBrazil.firstname);
            Console.Write(" birthdate in UTC time is ");
            Console.Write(playerInBrazil.birthdate);
            Console.Write(" and in my local time is ");
            //myTimeConvert =?
            Console.WriteLine(myTimeConvert);

        }

    }

    internal class Player
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public BsonDateTime birthdate { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public double goals { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean like this myTimeConvert = DateTimeOffset(playerInBrazil.birthdate); when I try it tells me that cannot be used like a method.

Comment: You can use `[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]` annotation on `birthdate` and C# driver will convert it for you.

Answer (score 1):

BsonDateTime has a .ToLocalTime() method that returns a DateTime

More info here http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDateTime_ToLocalTime.htm

Comment: I tried this myTimeConvert = playerInBrazil.birthdate.ToLocalTime; but I get an error - 
Error CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'ToLocalTime' to non-delegate type 'DateTime'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: @ikask You need parenthesis after the method name